# Angular 14 Unexpected token / in JSON at position 0 at makeWebpackError

Tags: angular, webpack-5, angular14

Angular 14 development build not working when enabling sourceMap true

```
[error] HookWebpackError: Unexpected token / in JSON at position 0
    at makeWebpackError (C:\Users\AK\Desktop\app\cc\node_modules\webpack\lib\HookWebpackError.js:48:9)
    at C:\Users\AK\Desktop\app\cc\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:3060:12
    at eval (eval at create (C:\Users\AK\Desktop\app\cc\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:44:1)
    at fn (C:\Users\AK\Desktop\app\cc\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:480:17)
    at _next2 (eval at create (C:\Users\AK\Desktop\app\cc\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:41:1)
    at eval (eval at create (C:\Users\AK\Desktop\app\cc\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:60:1)
-- inner error --

SyntaxError: Unexpected token / in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Users\AK\Desktop\app\cc\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\webpack\plugins\devtools-ignore-plugin.js:42:38
    at fn (C:\Users\AK\Desktop\app\cc\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:478:10)
    at _next2 (eval at create (C:\Users\AK\Desktop\app\cc\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:41:1)
    at eval (eval at create (C:\Users\AK\Desktop\app\cc\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:60:1)
```

Comment: Everything was working till yesterday and suddenly this issue started.

Comment: After removing --watch from build script, it started building with souceMap:true, it seems something got broke recently

Answer (score 1):

I have a commom issue because I have copied all the static files from an ASP.NET Core MVC web app including the "lib" folder. When I deleted it, everything is working fine now, so take a look on your static files. Hope it would help you!

Answer (score 1):

For me this issue was caused by an unnecessary include in my assets folder (it only occurred when `sourceMap: true` was set in angular.json). I added `--watch` to the serve command and it gave a good hint which file it was.

Comment: thank you for the hint with the assets folder! just had a similar problem... a file which was added like 2 years ago suddenly threw this error. while --watch didn't give me anything, the idea to expand my search to assets wasn't really crossing me..

Answer (score 0):

I had an empty `bootstrap.min.css.map` file in the assets folder that caused this issue.