# Angular 15 sourceMap webpack-dev-middleware: unexpected token | in JSON at position 3

Tags: angular, webpack-dev-middleware

I updated angular from 9 to 15 and now it seems I have issues running `ng s` with source Map enabled.

My Error:

```
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
<e> [webpack-dev-middleware] HookWebpackError: Unexpected token | in JSON at position 3
<e>     at makeWebpackError ([...]\node_modules\webpack\lib\HookWebpackError.js:48:9)
<e>     at [...]\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:3060:12
<e>     at eval (eval at create ([...]\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:61:1)
<e>     at fn ([...]\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:480:17)
<e>     at _next1 (eval at create ([...]\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:58:1)
<e>     at eval (eval at create ([...]\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:77:1)
<e>     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
<e> -- inner error --
<e> SyntaxError: Unexpected token | in JSON at position 3
<e>     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
<e>     at [...]\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\webpack\plugins\devtools-ignore-plugin.js:42:38
<e>     at fn ([...]\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:478:10)
<e>     at _next1 (eval at create ([...]\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:58:1)
<e>     at eval (eval at create ([...]\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:77:1)
<e>     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
<e> caused by plugins in Compilation.hooks.processAssets
<e> SyntaxError: Unexpected token | in JSON at position 3
<e>     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
<e>     at [...]\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\webpack\plugins\devtools-ignore-plugin.js:42:38
<e>     at fn ([...]\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:478:10)
<e>     at _next1 (eval at create ([...]\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:58:1)
<e>     at eval (eval at create ([...]\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:77:1)
<e>     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
```

I tried to add a development configuration in my angular.json

```
  "projects": {
    "myTrain": {
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/myTrain",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "vendorChunk": true,
            "extractLicenses": false,
            "buildOptimizer": false,
            "optimization": false,
            "namedChunks": true
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
             },
             "development": {
               "sourceMap": {
                 "scripts": true,
                 "styles": false,
                 "hidden": true,
                 "vendor": true
                 },
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "namedChunks": true,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "myTrain:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "myTrain:build:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

my dev dependencies:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.0.4",
    "@angular/cli": "^15.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.0.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "^15.0.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.2",
    "jasmine-core": "^4.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.8.4"
  }
```

node: 14.20.0

To ask this question, I need to provide more details, but I don't know what I could say to clarify the question further. I'm running an angular 15 app which was updated from angular 9 yesterday. I --force updated my way to 15, then updated dependencies via npm i and npm outdated. I know, Angular 15 is not using sourceMaps by default, but my problem is not to enable it, the system just isn't serving (`ng s`) with them enabled. Any questions welcome, I'm kinda lost here and google didn't help me as most related questions were telling me to use a development config.

Comment: right before your "serve" your are missing a comma

Comment: thanks added it. I do have it in my original angular.json, but I omitted a lot as they naturally tend to get crammed

Comment: I saw similar errors having package-lock.json in place.  I'm not quite sure but you can try unfreezing package.json by deleting package-lock.json and restore it later

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here: [Angular 14 Unexpected token / in JSON at position 0 at makeWebpackError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73104802/angular-14-unexpected-token-in-json-at-position-0-at-makewebpackerror)

Unfortunately I can't provide any more valuable information except:

This is a cheesy son of a bitch, the trace doesn't give you anything.

- Check your assets,
- run `ng serve -- watch`
- make a new project (same name) and copy the angular.json and package.json into your old one
- check your packages, upgrade or downgrade a version or webpack and/or angular

for me, a 2 year old unused file in the asset folder was causing the issue. it was a .map file and as all assets are loaded via http (and therefore json as default transfer), a pipe in the .map wasn't convertable.

Edit: I also had the problem that the angular.json wasn't correct after trying to fix it by hand. This I solved with point 3 above, I still don't fully understand the difference, but here's the working angular.json stub (more for me than for anyone else, sorry):

```
"architect": {
  "build": {
    [...]
    "configurations": {
      "production": {
        "budgets": [...]
        "outputHashing": "all"
      },
      "development": {
        "buildOptimizer": false,
        "optimization": false,
        "vendorChunk": true,
        "extractLicenses": false,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "namedChunks": true
      }
    },
    "defaultConfiguration": "production"
  },
  "serve": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "browserTarget": "myTrain:build:production"
        },
        "development": {
          "browserTarget": "myTrain:build:development"
        }
      },
      "defaultConfiguration": "development"
    },
```

so i assume:

- a serve configuration for development was missing
- default configuration: development under serve - otherwise it's using production
- a development configuration architect -> build -> configurations, not in architect -> serve -> configurations

Answer (score 0):

I've got simular error which appears from nowhere. Removing angular/.cache and  node_modules/* with reinstall helps.